# Substituting file extensions on a variable

Tags: shell-script, scripting, pdf, string, latex

I'd like to do the following : 
create a `.tex` and directly show it after compilation with evince, ideally it would be like this:

```
showpdf file.tex
```

so I wrote

```
#!/bin/sh
pdflatex $1 && evince ?
```

where the `?` is for something that would take `$1` and replace the `.tex` with a `.pdf`

Comment: OT: have you checked [latexmk](http://users.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean:

```
pdflatex "$1" && evince "${1%.tex}.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
pdflatex "$1" && evince "${1%.tex}.pdf"
```

where

- `${x%suffixe}` will delete `suffixe` from end of `${x}`